# Failed to execute 'function' on 'Document': 2 arguments required, but only 0 present

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy intentando llamar una función al momento en que se haga click en un botón, este es mi html:

```
<button id="evaluator-button" class="button-submit" onclick="evaluate()">Submit</button>
```

y el html está enlazado con un fichero js, donde tengo lo siguiente:

```
function evaluate () {
    console.log('Evaluate');
    let evaluator = document.getElementById('evaluator-input').value;
    let userLogin = document.getElementById('match-login').innerHTML;
    let actualPoints = document.getElementById('match-points').innerHTML;

    if (evaluator == 0) {
        return ;
    }
    else {
        console.log('The evaluation is in progress');
        let newPoints = parseInt(actualPoints) + parseInt(evaluator);
        fetch('http://localhost:3005/script/update', {
            method: 'PUT',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                login: userLogin,
                points: newPoints
            })
        });
    }
}
```

El error que obtengo por consola es el siguiente:

```
dashboard:106 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': 2 arguments required, but only 0 present.
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick
```

Alguien sabe que podría ser?, dice que espera argumentos pero en el prototipo de mi función no estoy esperando nada.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que [`evaluate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/evaluate) es un método de `document`.
Al disparse el evento, supone que se esta llamando a dicho método y no al definido por vos.

**Demo:**

```js
function evaluate() {
  console.log('?');
}
```

```html
<button onclick="evaluate()">Submit</button>
```

---

### Solución:

Podes simplemente cambiar el nombre de la función o invocarla usando el contexto global `window`.

**Ejemplo:**

```js
function evaluate() {
  console.log('?');
}
```

```html
<button onclick="window.evaluate()">Submit</button>
```